# Best method to show fixed Listview Data - Arraylist / sqlite / any other

Tags: java, android, listview

My app contains about 8 activities having different Listview's. As the data shown in each activity is constant (cannot be changed by user), what method should I use to save the listview items ?
Should I make a arraylist, sqlite db, or other method.

As the list may be long I want a easy structured method to add data on my PC then shown it on my app.

*Adding data is updating my app with latest list

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add data later on and have it updated on all user phones, you should make an API with a database behind it, where you can send an HTTP request to retrieve data for each list separately. 
This way, you can change list content however you want and it will be the same on all devices and you don't have to store it on the phone (maybe only cache it to reduce load on the API). The only bad side is that you need a server and a domain.

May I suggest some simple backends: Flask(Python) or NodeJS (Javascript).

Comment: Is there other way without using server, Offline app will be great if u suggest me a method for that!